# sed won't recognize numbers when passed as variables

Tags: sed, variable

This expression:

```
FN=27
LN=145
cat $FILENAME | sed -n $FN,$LNp
```

is failing with this error: "sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'"
but when I used actual numbers, I get the expected results. There are no special characters embedded, nor are there trailing or leading spaces

```
cat $FILENAME | sed -n 27,145p
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

Unless the `$LNp` variable is set, the `sed` command will be (assuming a default value of IFS as you forgot to quote your variable):

```
sed -n 27,
```

Here, you want:

```
sed -n "$FN,${LN}p" < "$FILENAME"
```

To tell the shell the `p` is not part of the variable name (`sed -n "$FN,$LN"p` would also work).

Or more efficiently to tell `sed` to stop as soon as the `$LN`<sup>th</sup> line is found:

```
sed "$FN,\$!d;${LN}q" < "$FILENAME"
```

or

```
tail -n "+$FN" < "$FILENAME" | head -n "$((LN - FN + 1))"
```

Comment: Awesome !! Everything is working now.